# How do I remove the private mode setting from my node? My node is not connecting to peer

Tags: node, private-mode, docker

I used below command to start my node container in private mode:

```
./mainnet.sh start --private-mode --no-bootstrap-peers --bootstrap-threshold=1 --connections 1 --peer public-node-ip
```

Node got started in private mode, but now it is not able to connect to public node ip and also when I stop and start my container using the below command, the private mode is not getting removed.

```
./mainnet.sh stop

./mainnet.sh start
```

How do I connect to the peer node while still in private mode, or how do I remove the private mode so that my baker doesn't stop functioning for now?

Comment: Is your command complete ? The final `--peer` expects an argument, which is the description of another node ('AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:PORT` or `HOSTNAME:PORT`)

Comment: Do you have a `config.json` file in your `~/.tezos-node` directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by an awkward behavior of the docker entrypoint script: it passes the node options along to `tezos-node config {init,update}` every time, which means options can accumulate and become impossible to remove through the entrypoint. :(

One option would be to just delete your config.json and start over: `./mainnet.sh shell`, then in the shell `rm /var/run/tezos/node/data/config.json`, then exit the shell and restart the node with the options you want. Or, edit the same config file by hand (say using `vi` in the docker shell) as FLF OCP suggests.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Yes if found the config.json file but i accidently left some incorrect configuration in it and now my docker container won't start and unless the container starts i can't login in to container shell. now i am stuck with my node container restarting again and again. Any solution for that?

Comment: D'oh! I am no docker expert, but, for me, it looks like the config file can be found at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/mainnet_node_data/_data/data/config.json` from outside the container. Perhaps you could delete or modify it (with `sudo`) at that location?

Comment: Thanks. That solves my problem. I found the volume with name mainnet_node_data, was mounted with the path mentioned by you.  /var/lib/docker/volumes/mainnet_node_data/_data/data/   Now my container is running again.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remain in private-mode, you must provide an argument `--peer node:port` when starting your node, or edit the `config.json` file of the node to add such peers (which is better, as it will be used everytime you restart it).